Ranking two list columns in polars based on elements in the first list, then the second
Due to certain restrictions, polars version is 0.18.4
Given a dataframe:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "column_id": [1,2,3],
    "column1": [[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,1]],
    "column2": [[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[0,2,1]]
})

What I want to do is to sort both column 1 and 2 descending by column1, then sort by column2 if column 1 has a tie.
What I have managed to do is to sort both column1 and column2 by column1 descending:
df_ranked = df.with_columns(
                    rank=pl.col('column1').list.eval( pl.element().rank(method="ordinal", descending=True) )
                    )

explode_col = ['column1','column2','rank']
rank = df_ranked['rank']

df_full_rank = (df_ranked.explode(explode_col)
            .select( pl.all().sort_by('rank').over('column_id') )
            .group_by('column_id', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col(explode_col))
            .with_columns(rank=rank)
      )

Output:
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_id ┆ column1   ┆ column2   ┆ rank      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1         ┆ [2, 1, 1] ┆ [0, 0, 0] ┆ [2, 1, 3] │
│ 2         ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [0, 1, 2] ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
│ 3         ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ [1, 0, 2] ┆ [2, 3, 1] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

But this is inadequate since it does not take into account the values in column2 when there is a tie.
Specifically, in the second row, even though in column1 all elements are tied, but because in column2 it is [0,1,2], the rank should be [3,2,1], since the last element has the biggest number. Similar logic applies for the 3rd row.
The expected output should be:
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_id ┆ column1   ┆ column2   ┆ rank      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1         ┆ [2, 1, 1] ┆ [0, 0, 0] ┆ [2, 1, 3] │
│ 2         ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2, 1, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
│ 3         ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘



explode() to unpack the lists.
arg_sort_by() to get indices of sorted data.
gather() to get elements by these indices.
group_by() and agg() to get results back.

(
    df.explode("column1","column2")
    .with_columns(rank = pl.arg_sort_by("column1","column2", descending=True).over("column_id"))
    .with_columns(pl.col("column1","column2").gather(pl.col.rank).over("column_id"))
    .group_by("column_id", maintain_order=True)
    .agg("column1","column2",pl.col.rank + 1)
)

┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_id ┆ column1   ┆ column2   ┆ rank      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1         ┆ [2, 1, 1] ┆ [0, 0, 0] ┆ [2, 1, 3] │
│ 2         ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2, 1, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
│ 3         ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

Alternatively

struct() to combine column1 and column2 into one column.
rank() to calculate rank.
sort_by() to sort column1 and column2 by rank.

(
    df.explode("column1","column2")
    .with_columns(rank = pl.struct("column1","column2").rank(descending=True, method="ordinal").over("column_id"))
    .with_columns(pl.col("column1","column2").sort_by("rank").over("column_id"))
    .group_by("column_id", maintain_order=True)
    .agg("column1","column2","rank")
)

┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_id ┆ column1   ┆ column2   ┆ rank      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1         ┆ [2, 1, 1] ┆ [0, 0, 0] ┆ [2, 1, 3] │
│ 2         ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2, 1, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
│ 3         ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

Alternatively

Here's one way:
First, explode the dataframe on column1 and column2.
Then, compute the rank column and sorted column1/column2 columns separately.
Finally, join the two dataframes.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "column_id": [1, 2, 3],
        "column1": [[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1]],
        "column2": [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1]],
    }
)

df = df.explode(["column1", "column2"])

rank = (
    df.select(
        "column_id",
        rank=pl.struct("column1", "column2")
        .rank("ordinal", descending=True)
        .over("column_id"),
    )
    .group_by("column_id", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col("rank"))
)

df = (
    df.sort(["column_id", "column1", "column2"], descending=[False, True, True])
    .group_by("column_id", maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col("column1"), pl.col("column2"))
    .join(rank, on="column_id")
)

print(df)

Output:
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_id ┆ column1   ┆ column2   ┆ rank      │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1         ┆ [2, 1, 1] ┆ [0, 0, 0] ┆ [2, 1, 3] │
│ 2         ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2, 1, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
│ 3         ┆ [1, 0, 0] ┆ [1, 2, 0] ┆ [3, 2, 1] │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

